# Marking nuget packages as not supported

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I got some content only nuget packages that will not work with the new `PackageReference` format.

There is no warning or error message when installing the package but their content will not be added. **Can I add something to the `.nuspec` so the user will know?** Since this is related to the project type and not the framework used I don't see an obvious way.

(I know how to use `ContentFiles` but some of my packages need to be deprecated and replaced with other things)

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest status about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add something to the .nuspec so the user will know?

You can include a `.txt` file into your .nuspec file to remind the user not use this package for project type `PackageReference` format.

To accomplish this, create a `.txt` with release notes, then included this file into `.nuspec`:

```
<files>
    <file src="readme.txt" target="" />      
</files>
```

Then pack this `.nuspec` file. Open the `.nupkg` with NuGet Package Explorer, you will notice that there is a file in the package:

[image]

When we install this package to the project, after install, the `.txt` file will display on the Visual Studio:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your answer. I know about the readme but the same file will show up regardless of project type which I think will be confusing. ProjectReference is not really a well known term. Also, it will not show for dependencies.